# How to ignore (or not get) clicks on interior of unfilled polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know of a way to make it so that my click handler is not called or if called can determine that click was on interior of unfilled (or fillOpacity of 0) polygon? (Polygon is NOT editable so path and vertex will not be included in click event)

I want to ignore such clicks and allow click to "bleed" through polygon, I only want to process clicks on polygon outline.

I suppose I could do something with the latlng of the click to determine if it is more then some number of pixels from an edge but that seems way to complicated, especially if strokeWeight and zoom levels need to be taken into account.

(I often have custom markers inside the polygon that I render myself by subclassing OverlayView and want to process clicks on them instead in such a case.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting clickable to false on the PolygonOptions didn't fix the issue? If not, try using a Polyline instead of a Polygon. Then you don't have to worry about clicks in the middle.

Comment: Yes, I might just do that. Create a clickable polyline for each polygons outline that is supposed to have an outline and draw all polygons with strokeWeight of 0 and unclickable. Will probably affect performance though when I need to render large amounts of polygons...